# Efficient algorithm to check duplicate rows in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, time-complexity

Given a matrix M of integers. Check if two rows are identical in the matrix. Give an optimum approach.

```
Example:
[{1, 2, 3},
 {3, 4, 5},
 {1, 2, 3}]
```

In the above matrix, rows 1 and 3 are identical.

Possible Solution:

```
Given a matrix, we can convert each row in a string (example using to_string()
method of C++ and concatenating each element in a row to a string). We do this
for every row of the matrix, and insert it in a table that is something like
(map<string, int> in C++). And hence, duplicate row can be checked in O(mn) time
for an mxn matrix.
```

Can I do better than this ? Or, above method has any flaw ?

Comment: I don't expect you can do better than O(mn) since in the worst case every element will need to be read.

Comment: That would be optimal, for the reason that @Matt had said. Just a caveat, you need to put some delimiter when you concatenate the elements. Otherwise `{1, 23}` and `{12, 3}` would be considered the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method works but you are wrong with the complexity of it.

Firstly, testing if an element is in a `std::map` has complexity `O(log(n) * f)`, where `n` is the number of elements in the map and `f` is an upper bound for the time required to comparing any two elements inserted/searched in the map.

In your case, every string has a length `m`, so comparing any two elements in the map costs `O(m)`.

So the total complexity of your method is:

`O(n * log(n) * m)` for inserting `n` strings in the map.

However, you can speed it up to `O(n * m)` in expectation, which is asymptotically optimal (because you have to read all the data), using a hash table rather than a map. The reason for this is that a hash table has `O(1)` average complexity for an insert operation and the hash function for every input string is computed only once.

In `C++` you can use the [unordered_set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the matrix, converting everything to a string seems like a pretty big waste of time and space.

Why not compute a likely unique hash for each row. For example, you could compute the bit-wise OR of all the entries, then save that hash, together with the index of the row, in a multimap. As you go through each row, you compute it's hash then check to see if that hash exists already. If it does, compare your row to the other rows with the same hash to see if they are equal.

This doesn't have better Big-O complexity, but it almost certainly has a smaller constant and uses less space.